# How to take all specific folders and take all files with specific extentions inside them on windows

Tags: django, windows, bash

I have all my django apps in one common project_apps dir. Inside it I had for example

```
-app_1
  -fixture
    -test
      test1.json
  models.py
  serializers..py
  urls.py
  views.py
-app_2
  -fixtures
    -test
      test2.json
  models.py
  serializers.py
  urls.py
  views.py
 ...
etc.
```

when I run this script on ubuntu

```
python manage.py loaddata ./project_apps/*/fixtures/test/*.json
```

it works fine. It takes all fixtures folders in project_apps and then takes all files in fixtures folder with extension .josn and loads the data.

All good, but when I run this script on Windows, i got this error

```
No fixture named '*' found.
```

How can I make it work on Windows?

Comment: Are you using a `bash` emulation, or just the Windows CMD or PowerShell prompt? Install Git Bash and use that, it should work fine.

Comment: Windows CMD otherwise i have installed Git Bash, but i run this script on CMD

Answer (score 1):

If you have Git Bash installed, you can probably just run `bash` from the CMD prompt like any other program, and it will execute as expected.

```
C:\Users\paul>type tst.bash
type tst.bash
#! /usr/bin/bash
pwd
date

C:\Users\paul>bash tst.bash
bash tst.bash
/c/Users/paul
Thu Jul 15 08:45:36 CDT 2021
```